# Time complexity of trim operation on a list

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity

What's the **time complexity** of **trim operation** on a list (example below)?

```py
def function():
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    x = list[2:]

    print(x)
```

I'm guessing that's **linear O(n)**, but not sure if that's the case.

Comment: What means "quadratic O(n)"?  That's an oxymoron...

Comment: What makes you think it is quadratic?

Comment: Doesn't it have to reassign all the indexes?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if quadratic or not. That's why I asked.

Comment: It is linear. Note, quadratic is O(N^2), linear is O(N).

Comment: Ohhhh, I see where's the confusion. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Comment: @Ritwik yes, the word isn't very obvious even to native English speakers. It comes from the latin word "quadratum", which means "square" as in x^2 ("x squared").